# Contact Form is not sending mails

Tags: forms, emails

I am new to Drupal. I am using Drupal 7 version in the WAMP local server. I had installed the customized Drupal theme in Drupal 7. In that customized theme i have a contact form but it is not sending emails. I did checked the email address at the contact form in structure(Admit toolbar) and also i checked the people authentication but i did not found the way to send an email in the contact form. Could you please assist me to get a solution for this.

Comment: Does php mail function work? Just place it in a php file and run it.

Answer (score 0):

May be mail server is not properly configured on your system.
So go for alternative :

You can use [SMTP Authentication Support](https://drupal.org/project/smtp) module and configure it.

> This module allows Drupal to bypass the PHP mail() function and send
>   email directly to  an SMTP server. The module supports SMTP
>   authentication and can even connect to servers  using SSL if supported
>   by PHP.

After proper configure you can send mail using external mail server like gmail, hotmail, yahoo etc.

Gmail smtp confguration are :

```
SMTP Port: 465
SMTP SERVER : smtp.gmail.com
Use encrypted protocol : SSL
```

Other configuration detail visit [here](https://support.google.com/mail/answer/13287)
 After all configuration your project will be able to send mail.